# How to read and separate segments of a txt file?

Tags: c#, text

I have a txt file, that has headers and then 3 columns of values (i.e)

Description=null

area = 100

1,2,3

1,2,4

2,1,5 ...

... 1,2,1//(these are the values that I need in one list)

Then another segment

Description=null

area = 10

1,2,3

1,2,4

2,1,5 ...

... 1,2,1//(these are the values that I need in one list).

In fact I just need one list per "Table" of values, the values always are in 3 columns but, there are n segments, any idea?
Thanks!

```
List<double> VMM40xyz = new List<double>();
            foreach (var item in VMM40blocklines)
            {
                if (item.Contains(','))
                {
                    VMM40xyz.AddRange(item.Split(',').Select(double.Parse).ToList());
                }
            }
```

I tried this, but it just work with the values in just one big list.

Comment: Did you write any code for this? What issue you are facing? The hint is to read the file line by line and check the line content and make the decision based on that.

Comment: Yes, I write a code for this, but it only work for the values in just one list, because I used an if statement that if the line contains a ','. Use the string.Split(',') to get the value.

Comment: The if statement is basically solved the problem for all lines. What do you desire here? Multiple `VMM40xyz` lists?

Comment: Yes! but how do I separate them? I mean, I need multiple Lists but separated each other by the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want your data to end up in a format like this:

```
public class SetOfData //Feel free to name these parts better.
{
    public string Description = "";
    public string Area = "";
    public List<double> Data = new List<double>();
}
```

...stored somewhere in...

```
List<SetOfData> finalData = new List<SetOfData>();
```

So, here's how I'd read that in:

```
public static List<SetOfData> ReadCustomFile(string Filename)
{
  if (!File.Exists(Filename))
  {
    throw new FileNotFoundException($"{Filename} does not exist.");
  }

  List<SetOfData> returnData = new List<SetOfData>();
  SetOfData currentDataSet = null;
  using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open))
  {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
      while (!reader.EndOfStream)
      {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        //This will start a new object on every 'Description' line.
        if (line.Contains("Description="))
        {
          //Save off the old data set if there is one.
          if (currentDataSet != null)
            returnData.Add(currentDataSet);

          currentDataSet = new SetOfData();
          //Now, to make sure there is something after "Description=" and to set the Description if there is.
          //Your example data used "null" here, which this will take literally to be a string containing the letters "null". You can check the contents of parts[1] inside the if block to change this.
          string[] parts = line.Split('=');
          if (parts.Length > 1)
            currentDataSet.Description = parts[1].Trim();
        }
        else if (line.Contains("area = "))
        {
          //Just in case your file didn't start with a "Description" line for some reason.
          if (currentDataSet == null)
            currentDataSet = new SetOfData();

          //And then we do some string splitting like we did for Description.
          string[] parts = line.Split('=');
          if (parts.Length > 1)
            currentDataSet.Area = parts[1].Trim();
        }
        else
        {
          //Just in case your file didn't start with a "Description" line for some reason.
          if (currentDataSet == null)
            currentDataSet = new SetOfData();

          string[] parts = line.Split(',');
          foreach (string part in parts)
          {
            if (double.TryParse(part, out double number))
            {
              currentDataSet.Data.Add(number);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      //Make sure to add the last set.
      returnData.Add(currentDataSet);
    }
  }

  return returnData;
}
```